# Restful web service in c# that has multiple Get with param

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, get

I need to have 2 Gets in my rest web service
the first Get takes 5 parameters, while the 2nd one takes 7 different parameters

I know that we can have default Get without parameters but how can we have 2 Gets with both have parameters?

thanks

both gets are needed

```
    public string Get(Int64 id, string UserID, int Val1, int Val2, int Val3)
{
}

    public int Get(string FirstName, string LastName, int Age, int Tall, int Size, string Code, string Address)
{
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add parameters? How did you do that? What was the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following tips if you want

```
// GET: api/Default
public IEnumerable<string> Get( string p1, string p2, string p3, string p4, string p5, string p6=null,string p7=null)
{

    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

if you pass 5 arguments your 6 and 7 will be null or 7 arguments with same action

Or you can define 2 gets like the following

```
// GET: api/Default
public IEnumerable<string> Get( string p1, string p2, string p3, string p4, string p5)
{

    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

and 7 parameters

```
// GET: api/Default
public IEnumerable<string> Get( string p1, string p2, string p3, string p4, string p5, string p6,string p7)
{

    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

you have to use the following uri for example

```
http://localhost:53383/api/default?p1=tes&p2=tesff&p3=tes&p4=tesffs&p5=tesffs
```

and for the action with 7 parameters

```
http://localhost:53383/api/default?p1=tes&p2=tesff&p3=tes&p4=tesffs&p5=tesffs&p6=tesp6&p7=tesp7
```

Comment: I need 2 gets as in the example I put above

Comment: just change the method overload to get the job done take a look at my  updates answer

Comment: this does not work! do i have to change the WebApiConfig.cs ?